# Silverlight Low Level Socket Support?

Tags: c#, silverlight, sockets, com

I have a Silverlight app that needs low-level socket support. It's an Out-of-Browser Trusted app, so it has more network permissions. But, I noticed that that Silverlight only supports limited TCP sockets, even with elevated permissions. The method "SetSocketOption" has been removed too. I didn't think that was too big of deal as I knew that I could integrated with COM components. I figured that I would just use Winsock and get on with it. However, the Winsock COM component isn't installed by default on Windows installations, so that won't work either.

It seems to me that this just isn't possible. Any other ideas or thoughts? Is there another COM component that supports socket programming?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no other COM components present by default that support Sockets.

Other ideas?  Ask the user to install the Winsock component or don't use Silverlight.

Comment: Unfortunately Anthony is exactly right.  The sockets are so limited in Silverlight that you either have to have the user install a certain COM component or you are going to have to use the limited TCP sockets.  Those really are the only available options.